# Building the new app-bundle for android dex errors at runtime

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I'm building the new android app-bundle following the instructions at https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/build but I'm getting an error when installing from the play store.

```
2018-06-04 11:06:09.397 10595-10595/? E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.org.app.ui.loading.LoadingFragment
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.b$a.a(FragmentNavigator.java:219)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.b$a.a(FragmentNavigator.java:202)
    at androidx.navigation.k.a(NavInflater.java:140)
    at androidx.navigation.k.a(NavInflater.java:169)
    at androidx.navigation.k.a(NavInflater.java:120)
        ... 36 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.org.app.ui.loading.LoadingFragment
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.b$a.a(FragmentNavigator.java:215)
        ... 40 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.org.app.ui.loading.LoadingFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/io.org.app-2KUWPMF_QJ31_iG8kGu1rA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/io.org.app-2KUWPMF_QJ31_iG8kGu1rA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/io.org.app-2KUWPMF_QJ31_iG8kGu1rA==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/io.prg.app-2KUWPMF_QJ31_iG8kGu1rA==/split_config.iw.apk", zip file "/data/app/io.org.app-2KUWPMF_QJ31_iG8kGu1rA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/io.org.app-2KUWPMF_QJ31_iG8kGu1rA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/io.org.app-2KUWPMF_QJ31_iG8kGu1rA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/io.org.app-2KUWPMF_QJ31_iG8kGu1rA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/io.org.app-2KUWPMF_QJ31_iG8kGu1rA==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/io.org.app-2KUWPMF_QJ31_iG8kGu1rA==/split_config.iw.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/io.org.app-2KUWPMF_QJ31_iG8kGu1rA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        ... 43 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/io.org.app-2KUWPMF_QJ31_iG8kGu1rA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:72)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:38)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:715)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:750)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:972)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5743)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1637)
            ... 6 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/io.org.app-2KUWPMF_QJ31_iG8kGu1rA==/split_config.en.apk
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
```

I've included the following in my build:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexKeepProguard file ('multidex-keep.pro')
        }
    }
}
```

multidex-keep.pro:

```
-keep class io.org.app.ui.main.** { *; }
-keep class io.org.app.ui.loading.** { *; }
```

Comment: Are your fragments written in Kotlin by chance?

Comment: Yes, why do you ask?

Comment: Did you `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` in said module?

Comment: Yes, Pierre's answer resolved the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the class `io.org.app.ui.loading.LoadingFragment` is loaded by reflection, but your proguard file doesn't prevent that class from being obfuscated, so it has been renamed which explains why it can't be found.

I imagine you should get the same error when you deploy the release version of your app locally.

Try tweaking the proguard file to prevent the renaming of that class.

Comment: Interesting, I'm using the new navigation library but I assumed it was generating code through an annotation processor. Do you know if this is the culprit?

Comment: Looks like you're right, I added `-keep class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {}` to my proguard and it worked

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem.
Check that you add:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

in your **build.gradle** files.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. None of the above works. Cause it's compilerOptions error.

```
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below I'm listing possible solutions,
try this steps one by one:

- #### 1  Delete app on device and Clean Project
- #### 2 Disable **minifyEnabled** in debug mode

go to build.gradle(Module: app) in debug block and disable minifyEnabled:

```
buildTypes {

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false

     }
}
```

- #### 3 Setting dataBinding to true in application's gradle file

In my case, I was including another layout
`<include layout="@layout/attached_layout" />`
to my activity's layout and this solved it.

```
    android {
    ...
    ...
    ...

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    }
```

- #### 4 Check the relative path of your activities in manifest

eg:

```
<activity android:name="com.myExactPackageName.MyActivity"
```

- #### 5 Check the package names in your custom views

  ```
  <com.myExactPackageName.MyCustomView
      android:id="@+id/myview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
  ```
- #### 6 Try disabling pre-dexing in the app build.gradle:

  ```
  dexOptions {
   preDexLibraries false
  }
  ```
- #### 7 Disable Instant Run

  Go to File -> Settings -> Build,Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> Uncheck the checkbox for instant run
- #### 8 Try MultiDexApplication

And this in build.gradle(Module:app)

```
android { 

defaultConfig {
      ...
      multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
     ... 
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}


}
```

if you are using application class you have to extend it with `MultiDexApplication` instead of `Application` and add it to application tag in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:name="com.myPackageName.MyApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

else add `MultiDexApplication` class path from library as name

```
<application
    android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```