# DJI app error (No original dex files found for dex location)

Tags: android, sdk, dji-sdk

I am basically trying to convert the DJI videostreamdecodingsample to a kotlin based app but when I tried to run the app then it shows the following error

```
2018-12-10 15:12:02.031 5208-5227/com.joeydash.djilogapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.joeydash.djilogapp, PID: 5208
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ldji/sdk/sdkmanager/DJISDKManager;
    at com.joeydash.djilogapp.ConnectionActivity$startSDKRegistration$1.run(ConnectionActivity.kt:83)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at 

com.joeydash.djilogapp.ConnectionActivity$startSDKRegistration$1.run(ConnectionActivity.kt:83) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.joeydash.djilogapp-UOs6TJS_aks11EEvG3Rv7w==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
2018-12-10 15:12:02.032 5208-5227/com.joeydash.djilogapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:35)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:693)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:727)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:954)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5639)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I made minifyEnabled false in debug build but still it doesn't works
I am not getting what the error is

Comment: pls show me your build.gradle

Comment: maybe this would help https://stackoverflow.com/a/54509773/6017001