# Unable to show layout preview and InflateException after migrated to Android X

Tags: android, android-xml, androidx, android-9.0-pie

This morning I decided to migrate all app to Android X to use some new feature, but I got several problems, most of it in these three layout, (activity_main.xml, app_bar_main.xml, content_main.xml)

[image]

[image]

When I run the app I got this errors

```
    2019-03-04 12:30:18.948 28112-28112/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: www.pro_cs_is.com, PID: 28112
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{www.pro_cs_is.com/www.pro_cs_is.com.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class CoordinatorLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6653)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:821)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class CoordinatorLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class CoordinatorLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.CoordinatorLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/www.pro_cs_is.com-MQHeR58522USvJ7r2TTHzQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/www.pro_cs_is.com-MQHeR58522USvJ7r2TTHzQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/www.pro_cs_is.com-MQHeR58522USvJ7r2TTHzQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/www.pro_cs_is.com-MQHeR58522USvJ7r2TTHzQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/www.pro_cs_is.com-MQHeR58522USvJ7r2TTHzQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/www.pro_cs_is.com-MQHeR58522USvJ7r2TTHzQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/www.pro_cs_is.com-MQHeR58522USvJ7r2TTHzQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/www.pro_cs_is.com-MQHeR58522USvJ7r2TTHzQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/www.pro_cs_is.com-MQHeR58522USvJ7r2TTHzQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/www.pro_cs_is.com-MQHeR58522USvJ7r2TTHzQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/www.pro_cs_is.com-MQHeR58522USvJ7r2TTHzQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/www.pro_cs_is.com-MQHeR58522USvJ7r2TTHzQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/www.pro_cs_is.com-MQHeR58522USvJ7r2TTHzQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/www.pro_cs_is.com-MQHeR58522USvJ7r2TTHzQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:610)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:707)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:724)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:792)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:969)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:141)
        at www.pro_cs_is.com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7098)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7089)
2019-03-04 12:30:18.949 28112-28112/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2895)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1616)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6653)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:821)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/www.pro_cs_is.com-MQHeR58522USvJ7r2TTHzQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:35)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:695)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:729)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:956)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2282)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5725)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1685)
                ... 6 more
```

**build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "testApp.com"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4', {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    })
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-blogger:v3-rev57-1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.1'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:5.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    // ViewModel and LiveData
    dependencies {
        def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"

        // ViewModel and LiveData
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
        implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
        // optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
        implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:$lifecycle_version"
        // For Kotlin use lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx
        // optional - Test helpers for LiveData
        testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"
    }
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
    }

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

about this error `No original dex files found for dex location` I tried the solution in this [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897739/java-io-ioexception-no-original-dex-files-found-for-dex-location), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52269042/no-original-dex-files-found-for-dex-location) but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this material design library and make sure all of your widgets are `androidx`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
```

The `recyclerview` and `navigationView` are **not part of androidx material design** it should be :- ( you are using older design version of recyclerview and NavigationView )

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
     .....
     .....
```

&&

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     .....
     .....
```

**Edit**

> Make sure you upgrade every widget to androidx .

The appbar widget should be

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
```

Answer (score 2):

`CTRL + Shift + F` and found all `CoordinatorLayout`. 
Then check if `CoordinatorLayout` elements has this signiture in xml files: `androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout`